# Extracting the arguments of a function using Inspect

Tags: python, inspect

I am trying to get the arguments of functions using,

```
args, varargs, keywords, defaults = inspect.getargspec(globals()[functionName])
```

But, this gives me an error if the function name starts with an underscore(i.e, '_func' or '__func').
How can I solve this?

The error message is,
`NameError: name '_add' is not defined`

Comment: Can you post the exception message?

Comment: @funnydman I updated the question with the error message

Comment: Are these functions that you retrieved with `from nameOfModule import *`?  That type of import omits names starting with an underscore by default.

Comment: @jasonharper Yes, I am trying to get the arguments of a function defined in a python file from another file. But for the functions defined inside a class, I do ```args, varargs, keywords, defaults = inspect.getargspec(
        getattr(eval(className), str(functionName)))``` , Here it does not give me any error witha single underscore.

Comment: A class never actually contains attribute names starting with two underscores - you'd have to retrieve them via their mangled name, `_className__methodName`.